# Why is a const templated reference type different from a const reference type?

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, dynamic-cast

Consider this template:

```
template< typename T, typename RefT = T& >
class foo
{
    typedef const RefT const_ref_t;
    typedef const T&   another_const_ref_t;

    //...

};
```

I would assume that the types `const_ref_t` and `another_const_ref_t` would be equivalent. Both are `const T&`'s. Yet they are not. Alas, the following demonstration of their not-equivalence is fairly elaborate. It hinges on using `dynamic_cast<>` to check the type of of another class.

```
class abstractBase
{
public: virtual ~abstractBase() {}
};

template< typename T >
class otherClass : public abstractBase
{
};

template< typename T, typename RefT = T& >
class foo
{
    typedef const RefT const_ref_t;
    typedef const T&   another_const_ref_t;

public:
    void discover( abstractBase* p )
    {
        otherClass< const_ref_t >* a = 
            dynamic_cast< otherClass< const_ref_t >* >( p );
        otherClass< another_const_ref_t >* b = 
            dynamic_cast< otherClass< another_const_ref_t >* >( p );

        assert( a );    // Fails
        assert( b );    // Succeeds
    }
};

void fn()
{
    abstractBase* p = new otherClass< const int& >();
    foo< int > f;
    f.discover( p );   // Assertion on 'a' fails.
}
```

Sorry this is so complex, but it's a simplified version of the situation where I discovered the question.

The question, then, is this. This code treats `const int&`, `foo< int >::const_ref_t`, and `foo< int >::another_const_ref_t` as equivalent, which seems reasonable given the typedefs. Yet `dynamic_cast<>` only treats `foo< int >::another_const_ref_t` as equivalent to `const int&`. It will return null in the other (`foo< int >::const_ref_t`) case.

Why?

Comment: I'm guessing you already realize this, but for the benefit of other readers, I'll point out that although `a == NULL` in this version, `a != NULL` if you change `typename RefT = T&` to `typename RefT = const T&`. (At least, when I tried this in g++ 4.5.2.)

Comment: You can also test types at compile-time: http://ideone.com/mAc9u

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider this:

```
typedef Foo T;
typedef T & TRef;
typedef T const & TCRef;
```

Now `TRef` is the same as `Foo &`, and `TCRef` is the same as `const Foo &`.

However, `const TRef` is the same as `const (TRef) = const (Foo &)`, not `(const Foo)&`. But reference types are always constant, so the additional `const` doesn't add anything.

If you prefer the comparison with pointers: `T&` is essentially like `T * const`, so `TRef const` is like `(T * const) const`, which just collapses to `T * const`.

Comment: do you mean 'TCRef const is like (T* const) const' ?

Comment: @sashang: No. `TCRef` is like `T const * const`, as is `TCRef const`. Adding a `const` to the reference type itself does nothing.

Comment: I buy that. I suspected something like this was going on. But it raises a follow-up question: for defining a class template like `foo` above, is there any other way of setting reasonable default reference types than to add a third template parameter: `template< typename T, typename RefT = T&, typename ConstRefT = const T& > class foo {...};`?

Comment: @Dimbleby: Use any of the `std::remove_reference`-like typetraits.